# Combining static text and EL expression for another EL expression

Tags: jsp, el

So i've check other identical questions  but they're not quite the same, or answer was different for my case. Here's what i have:
On the server i set an attribute,

> request.getSession().setAttribute(tableField.getSiglaId()+"_rowSize",new Integer(tableSize));

And in the jsp file i'm trying to get this attribute value, but since you can't nest el expressions, i used the core tag library to set a new variable:

```
<c:set var="trueRowSize" value="${field.siglaId}_rowSize" />
```

Typing ${trueRowSize} will give the output "timers_rowSize".But i want to get the attribute with the said name.If i type ${timers_rowSize} it will give the correct value i want.

Using:

```
 ${requestScope[trueRowSize]}
```

Doesn't seem to be working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your attribute in the session:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute(...);
```

so you won't find it in requestScope, but in sessionScope:

```
${sessionScope[trueRowSize]}
```

Comment: Thanks, i was just testing without using the .getSession but for some reason the attribute returns empty.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can nest the expressions. Well, sort of. c:set tag can take it's value from the body of itself, so you can have things like the following:

```
<c:set var="trueRowSizeText">
  My true row size is: <c:out value='request.getSession().setAttribute(tableField.getSiglaId()+"_rowSize",new Integer(tableSize));'/>
</c:set>
```

Also have a look at this similar question - [Nested expression in JSP/JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351116/nested-expression-in-jsp-jstl)