# Spring message in JSTL Tag

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

According to this [post from 3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351116/nested-expression-in-jsp-jstl) the only way to display a spring message in a jstl tag is to wrap it in a `<c:set var="someVar">` which does "work" but it seems very far from ideal.

Fast forward 3 years, is this still the only way to handle this?

Here is my code

Works, but not "ideal"

```
<c:set var="closeMessage">
    <spring:message code='lman.ilr.closeItemDetail'/>
</c:set>
<dsg:sidePanelContent closePanelText="${closeMessage}">
```

Doesn't work, returns a string of `<spring:message code='lman.ilr.closeItemDetail'/>`

```
<dsg:sidePanelContent closePanelText="<spring:message code='lman.ilr.closeItemDetail'/>">
```

Comment: As I don't use it, I'm not sure Spring MVC made progress in those 3 years. One way you could try to check if the `ResourceBundle` instance isn't available as some request attribute. If so, then you could make use of plain EL like so `${bundleAttributeName['lman.ilr.closeItemDetail']}`. At least, JSF works that way.

Comment: Uh, it's just part of standard Java SE since ages and used by `<spring:message>` under the covers. Did you bother to explore the available request attributes if there isn't such one?

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273958/ddg#5725063

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The spring message tag, just as `fmt:message`, has a var attribute that can be used to store the message instead of displaying it.

It always helps to read [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring.tld.message).

Also, your wrong message probably comes from forgettin to declare the spring taglib at the top of your JSP.

Comment: JB,  The wrong message and the working / non ideal are on the same JSP, and spring is declared.

Comment: @JBNizet thank trick with <spring:message var="label" code='my.message.text'/> works great for me!

Answer (score 5):

In case for reference,

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${serviceVO.id eq 0}"> 
     <spring:message code="label.service.createservice" var="buttonName"/> 
  </c:when> 
  <c:otherwise>
    <spring:message code="label.updateservice" var="buttonName"/> 
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<c:out value="${buttonName}"> //Prints the desired value...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you wanna do is.

```
<spring:message code='lman.ilr.closeItemDetail' var="closeMessage"/>
```

Then

```
<dsg:sidePanelContent closePanelText="${closeMessage}">
```

Answer (score 0):

As above mentioned,

```
<spring:message code='lman.ilr.closeItemDetail' var="closeMessage"/>

<dsg:sidePanelContent closePanelText="${closeMessage}">
```

works, since  tag has the attribute "var" for above purpose.
tested with spring boot app and it works.

Comment: This should be a comment.