# generic linking, variables and paths in jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, internationalization, jstl

**`Requests:`** Please only answer if you know implications in depth.

Related Question that I found help from: [Nested expression in JSP/JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351116/nested-expression-in-jsp-jstl)

I want to make my links, paths, and variables (for images, scripts, and other pages and includes) generic so that refactoring or changes file locations in future would make no big problems.

What I thought was to make:

variables.jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<c:set var="mainDir" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/view/jsp" />
<c:set var="resourcesDir" value="${mainDir}/resources" />
```

header.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@include file="variables.jsp" %>
<html>
   <head><title>${pageTitle}</title></head>
```

login.jsp

```
<c:set var="pageTitle" >
    <spring:message code="pageTitle.login" />
</c:set>
<%@include file="${mainDir}/common/header.jsp" %>

<body>...
...
...
<%@include file="${mainDir}/common/footer.jsp" %>
```

Please observe the includes and c:sets / c:outs with spring:messages.

**What is the proper way to do what I want to (if my current strategy is not sane)**.

Comment: As to `<c:set>` tag, just omit `<c:out>`. This is JSP 1.x style. Since JSP 2.0 (over a decade old already), EL is natively supported in template. Surely you aren't using JSP 1.x anymore. As to Spring tag, no idea.

Comment: @BalusC sorry i didnt got you. what do you suggest as an alternative then? (for As to <c:set> tag, just omit <c:out>.) how to print the variable then?

Comment: You don't need to use `<c:out>` to get `${}` to work. This is only applicable in JSP 1.x/JSTL 1.0. Since JSP 2.0, just use `<c:set var="resourcesDir" value="${mainDir}/resources" />`. Your JSTL taglib URIs are from JSTL 1.1/1.2 which suggests that you're already on at least JSP 2.0.

Comment: ok. i will edit my post to reflect that. but other than that the problems stated at bottom. e.g  `<c:set var="pageTitle" value="<spring:message code="pageTitle.login" />" />`   are not fixed

Comment: As said, I have no idea. I'm no Spring user nor am I interested in using it.

Comment: Thanks! but Its a general question on how to <c:set things that have `< / > "` etc

Comment: Looks like `<spring:message>` has just a `var` attribute like as JSTL's own `<fmt:message>`: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/taglib/tag/MessageTag.html This way you don't need the whole `<c:set>` around it at all.

Comment: updated my question. Thanks uptil here!