# images, scripts and resources link path not loaded using spring and tomcat

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, spring-mvc

**`Status`**: solved.

Here is my directory structure.

[image]

and other dir structure and structure of .war file on right side.

[image]

---

Edit 1 start

I just researched and saw my other projects. its not a problem of tomcat or jsp. I did similar in earlier projects. The only difference was that I included `spring` and `maven` this time and I had jsps, images, scripts outside the `WEB-INF` dir. but in the `web` dir

(but I may be wrong)

I do also get `WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ttmaven/resources/images/person.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springDispatcher'`

**I think it may be a problem of filters or url patterns.**  `http://localhost:8084/ttmaven/resources/images/person.png`   passes the request to a servlet and that servlet does not handles it correctly?

Edit 1 end

---

I am using spring and controllers.

E.g `localhost/appName/login` gives me `WEB-INF/view/jsp/login/login.jsp`

`prefix` is `/view/jsp`.

I have really tried every possible combination to link up the images and .css files in my jsps. For example in login.jsp.

I always get `404 error`.

Even for a direct link e.g `ttmaven` as my appname. `http://localhost:8084/ttmaven/resources/images/person.png` dont work

What is the proper way to link?
and if I used spring security too, how to allow the resources/** for all to access.

**My related questions**

[pageContext.request.contextPath and generic linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038955/pagecontext-request-contextpath-and-generic-linking)

[generic linking, variables and paths in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028466/generic-linking-variables-and-paths-in-jsp)

**web.xml** (I commented out spring security things to be sure that its not spring security permissions which is making problems)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>



<!--    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>-->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
<!--            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml-->
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml mainly only has:

```
 <import resource="springDispatcher-servlet.xml" />
```

springDispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd"
>


    <context:component-scan base-package="web" >
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service"       />
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"    />
    </context:component-scan> 
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
<!--  <context:annotation-config />-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<!--          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">-->

<!--             class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" >-->
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>        

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController">
          <property name="viewName" value="index" />
    </bean>



     <!---
     ##########################################################################
    Hibernate

    -->
<!--    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="abc" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="web.entity" />
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>

        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    ###########################################################
    -->


<!--

    JPA based instead of hibernate

-->
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<!-- 
        This configures the EntityManagerFactory object used for JPA/Spring managed persistent objects. 
     -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistence-unit-demo" /> 
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="packagesToScan" value="web.entity" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                                <property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL" />
<!--    giving errors       <property name="databasePlatorm" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>-->
<!--                                <property name="database" value="HSQL" />-->  
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />                        
            </bean>
        </property>   
                <property name="jpaProperties">
                    <props>
<!--                        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>-->
                            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>                         
    </bean> 
    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    <!-- Pulls database connection from the tomcat container's context database pool via JNDI -->
<!--    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/mssqlserver" resource-ref="true"/>-->

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
            <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" />
            <property name="username" value="postgres" />
            <property name="password" value="abc" />
        </bean>



    <!--
        Sets up our transaction manager. 
     -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<!-- giving errors               <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
                </property>-->
    </bean>

        <!--
        Defines our transaction manager for Transactional annotations.
     -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" factory-bean="entityManagerFactory" factory-method="getSessionFactory" />




        <!--Internationalization ########################## -->

        <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
        <property name="interceptors">
           <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
           </list>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <!-- Register the welcome.properties -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Answer (score 4):

Resources that a browser will request directly, such as images, CSS, and JavaScript, cannot be under the `/WEB-INF` folder. That folder is not accessible through a web browser. Move your web resources up to the webapp folder. Then, link to them using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/person.png`.

Your structure should look like this:

```
/webapp
  /css
  /images
    /person.png
  /scripts
  /WEB-INF
    /view
      /jsp
```

And so forth and so on...

Comment: your answer made sence but I have followed it. (see changed snapshot) but same 404 error again.

Comment: If you request the image directly in a browser, does it work? What does the rendered HTML output look like?

Comment: No steven Benitez e.g ttmaven as my appname. `http://localhost:8084/ttmaven/resources/images/person.png` dont workk

Comment: What does your web.xml look like?

Comment: I just pasted all my xmls in the question.

Comment: added the .war structure snap too. I am very disturbed why error occurs.

Comment: I just Made and Edit 1

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution: just had to add `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` in `springDispatcher xml`

**Helpful link:**

[Not displaying images in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847247/not-displaying-images-in-spring-mvc)
http://www.coderanch.com/t/595112/Spring/find-css-images-js-static
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?97061-The-lt-mvc-resources-gt-does-not-work

Indirect help:

[No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/pages/apiForm.jsp]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266303/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-web-inf-pages-apiform-jsp)